# Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am using the [Python Stripe package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stripe/). I get the error `Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0`. I am using Python 2.7 on Mac. How do I fix this?

```
# Set this to your Stripe secret key (use your test key!)  
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_VAjLc9DN9BXMS3GPvFn5W92c"   

# Get the credit card details   
token = info['stripeToken']  
amount = info['amount']   
description = info['description']  

# Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card   
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
    amount=amount,
    currency="usd",
    card=token,
    description=description
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vertace/Desktop/payableApp-Sumup/payableAppServer.py", line 23, in pay
    description=description
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stripe/resource.py", line 466, in create
    response, api_key = requestor.request('post', url, params, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 140, in request
    resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 288, in interpret_response
    self.handle_api_error(rbody, rcode, resp, rheaders)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 163, in handle_api_error
    rheaders)
AuthenticationError: Request req_A4IYdjtgwILuyV: Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later. You can learn more about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.
```

Comment: Please see [Stripe - PHP error - Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438053/stripe-php-error-stripe-no-longer-supports-api-requests-made-with-tls-1-0)

Comment: Am using Xcode 7.2.1. If i try to install TLS 1.2 it shows You need Xcode 8.2 to install TLS 1.2. But if i move my code from xcode 7.2 to xcode 8.2 it shows error. What can i do?

Answer (score 5):

```
pip install pyopenssl

pip uninstall requests

pip install requests
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide some explanation as to why this fixes the problem.

Comment: The solution worked for me, but as @Graham pointed out, it would be very helpful to provide some explanation. I couldn't find anything in the Stripe documentation regarding the incompatibility with pyopenssl. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and the following solution solved the issue. (Working on Mac OS Sierra)

1. First check if you have python running from Os-installed version or installed via Homebrew. For this, you can run

   ```
   which python
   ```

If you get as result **/usr/bin/python** means you are running Python from your OS version. If this occurs, run (asssuming you already have installed homebrew).

```
    brew install python
```

Maybe, instead you may need

```
    brew link --overwrite python
```

This will led to install a new version of Python and this is the version you will be working instead.

2. Install virtualenv on your new brew Python version.

   ```
   pip install virtualenv
   ```

It is neccesary to check that virtualenv is not pointing to Python OS-installed version. This can be check running (from your activated env)

```
    nano $(which virtualenv)
```

3. Check that the first line is pointing to

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```

Run this same path on your terminal and check that Python version is the same as the one you installed via Homebrew (/usr/local/bin/python)

4. Activate your virtualenv environment (source env/bin/activate), install your dependencies (pip install 'your requirements file') and run your server.
5. Test your Stripe flow. Should be working successfully now.

Answer (score 0):

Set the apache configuration with the following in ssl.conf
SSLProtocol -All  +TLSv1.2

Answer (score 0):

Following the exact same instruction can solve the problem: https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2#python

```
sudo pip install pyOpenSSL backports.ssl requests
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, I had this issue with these versions of pyOpenSSL and requests:

pyopenssl==17.2.0

requests==2.6.0

To solve it, I've upgraded both of them to these versions:

pyopenssl==17.3.0

requests==2.18.4

To upgrade them do:

`pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
pip install requests --upgrade`